# The noun "it" points to

Tags: pronouns

The following is an excerpt from a passage from ETS, operator of TOEFL test. I wonder, which name the pronoun "it" points to.

> The tradition of religious sculpture extends over most historical periods but is less clearly delineated than that of stonewares or porcelains, for it embraces the old custom of earthenware burial ceramic with later religious images and architectural ornament."

Answer (score 3):

"tradition", or more completely "the tradition of religious sculpture"

Work pragmatically:  Which noun could be said to "embrace the old custom...". "Tradition" is also the only singular noun that isn't functioning as a modifier of another noun; sculpture is a modifier of "tradition" and "periods", "stonewares" and "porcelains" are all plural.